# How to fix wireless debugging failures in Android Studio on Windows 10?

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

I'm trying to use wifi debugging in Android Studio, but I'm having near-endless connection issues. Most of the time, when I go into "Pair new devices over Wi-Fi", my computer will not respond at all when my phone scans the QR code. When it does detect my phone after scanning the QR code and starts trying to connect, it often fails.

If I try to pair using a pairing code, it never detects my device.

On the very rare occasion I do manage to get them to connect, the connection lasts until the next time my computer goes to sleep and then my computer is seemingly unaware of it (though my computer does still show up on my phone's list of paired devices).

I'm running Windows 10, Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1, and Android 12 on a Pixel 6.

Comment: I have the same problem, interested in a solution as well!

Comment: Im having the same problem. At first it was connecting fine but all of a sudden it just fails to pair. Via cable it connects fine, adb runs fine.

Comment: It's not connected to galaxy A03 and iqooz3

Comment: Having the same issue. Pairing seems to work but after a period of time lose connection with device. Restarting Android Studio seems to reinitiate the connection for me. Would really like to avoid the restart since it syncs with a universe for an hour on restart!

Answer (score 0):

I am running Android Studio Giraffe on Ubuntu 22.04 and experiencing the exact same issues in October, 2023. The comment above by Robby Lebotha, "Via cable it connects fine, adb runs fine." prompted me to connect the cable, allow Android Studio to connect via USB, then go to the wireless pairing. Wireless pairing worked flawlessly, and now with the cable disconnected Wireless Debugging is working fine. Using a USB cable for the initial connection may not be ideal, but it works for now...until I learn a better way!

FWIW here's the Android Studio About output:

```
    Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2
    Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.10811636, built on September 14, 2023
    Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231 amd64
    VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
    Linux 6.2.0-34-generic
    GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
    Memory: 3072M
    Cores: 6
    Registry:
        external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
        ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
        ide.instant.shutdown=false
Current Desktop: ubuntu:GNOME
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure the solution found for this issue but repeating this info may be helpful to some.

Found an answer on [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70944858/android-studio-wifi-pairing-issue-on-windows).

---

In Android Studio:

```
File -> Settings -> Debugger
```

on the right you will find a section called:

```
Android Debug Bridge (adb)
```

Under that section there is a checkbox that says:

```
Enable adb mDNS for wireless debugging
```

Uncheck the box and hit apply, await changes then check the box and hit apply.

Along with this solution the commenter mentioned allowing `adb.exe` through windows defender.

It was already allowed on my machine.  There is an extended solution I am working on following as well.

Results:  When I cannot connect to my device or if my device loses connectivity then this will allow my device to connect and run wireless debugging until it loses connectivity again.

I am not certain why this works but it does seem to work for a time.  A more permanent solution would be preferable, but this will work till found.

---

My current setup information.

Galaxy S20 FE

```
Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.10671973, built on August 17, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10 10.0
```