# Android Studio Wifi pairing Issue on Windows

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-sdk-tools

I have used Android Studio Bumblebee's latest function (Wifi pairing) for 2 - 3 days before it stopped working.
I am now receiving the error "**This system does not meet the requirements to support Wi-Fi pairing. Please update to the latest version of "platform-tools" using the SDK manager**"

I have updated everything to the latest version.

[image: Screenshot of the error message]

Comment: I have already tried to reinstall the Android platform tools. And also added the path variable. But still, I am facing the same issue.

Comment: spent 3 days trying to figure out this,
turns out, adb tries to spin up a mdns server on port 5353 and doesn't do any proper error reporting failing that.
there is a default windows service that uses that port (don't know if it always uses it or just bad luck) called DNScache, so finding a way to change the port that this service uses or the adb port sould fix it, but i got no luck doing that

Comment: I just restarted my system to fix this issue

Comment: I tried every one for your suggestions. But I am still facing this issue.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had to set the environment variable `ADB_MDNS_OPENSCREEN` to `1`.

Here's my PowerShell code:

```
$env:ADB_MDNS_OPENSCREEN=1
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

This is because MDNS is disabled by default in v 31.0.2:
https://source.android.com/devices/automotive/virtualization/tools

Answer (score 143):

I had a similar problem and managed to solve it the following way:

**Quick fix**

1. In Android Studio, File -> Settings
2. Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger
3. Under Android Debug Bridge (adb), **uncheck** 'Enable adb mDNS for wireless debugging' and Apply
4. Wait some seconds for changes to take effect
5. Recheck 'adb mDNS for wireless debugging' and Apply
6. On the pop-up window from Windows Defender, **allow network access** to adb

**Extended sollution**
By checking the Android Studio logs (Help -> Show Log in Explorer) you can find an error message regarding the *adb mDNS daemon*.

> INFO - ireless.WiFiPairingServiceImpl - 'adb mdns check' (not supported) result:
> INFO - ireless.WiFiPairingServiceImpl -     ERROR: mdns daemon unavailable
> INFO - ireless.WiFiPairingServiceImpl - Checking if mDNS is supportState result: NotSupported

If you run that command in e.g. Powershell (`adb mdns check`) you will see that you get the exact same error message. After some research I found out you could disable this mDNS service in the Andoid Studio settings.

1. File -> Settings
2. Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger
3. Under Andoird Debug Bridge (adb), uncheck 'Enable adb mDNS for wireless debugging'
4. Hit apply
5. Recheck 'adb mDNS for wireless debugging'
6. Hit apply

Now a pop-up window should appear asking you to allow adb network access. Click on **allow access**.
Wi-Fi pair should work now.

See also: [Pairing new device on Android Studio BumbleBee over Wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70903567/pairing-new-device-on-android-studio-bumblebee-over-wifi/)

Comment: This did not work for me because I already had ADB added for my inbound connections. I had to manually add adb.exe to my outbound settings in Windows Defender. It worked after that.

Comment: Worked for me, though I had to restart Android Studio for the QR code to work.

Comment: It worked on my Linux machine, (I'm using Manjaro-GNOME env) but there was no prompt to allow permission, this acquired permission automatically once I unchecked and checked the option again.

Comment: Now I have `connection to device that takes up to 2 minutes` and it fails after some time

Comment: This worked for me after following the steps and restarting the studio

Comment: This worked for me without restarting anything.  Instantly worked!  :)

Comment: Excellent solution. It saved my lot of time. By just uncheck and checking the adb mDNS my problem resolved.

Comment: This worked for me with Android Studio Dolphin on Fedora 36. Uncheck and recheck the adb mDNS option. No restart required.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. It worked for me straight away.

Comment: In my case (Windows 11) - Dolphin studio, i must check use mDNS instead of uncheck, but it helps. So thanks for hint.

Comment: Also works on Android Studio Giraffe on windows

Answer (score 12):

Worked for me --> I tried below steps,

1. unistall previous installed platform-tools and install again
2. uncheck and check again in Android Studio Sesttings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger -> 'Enable adb mDNS for wireless debugging' then apply
3. Invalid caches in File then check all checks then click on 'Invalidate caches and Restart'

Comment: Just unchecking/apply and rechecking/apply was all that was needed on my machine. Would never have found the mDNS option!

Answer (score 6):

My guess is that you have an old version of platform-tools/adb installed somewhere (you can verify this by running `which adb` in your command prompt).

### Find the right platform-tools

You can find the pathway to the platform-tools/adb you want to use in Android Studios under Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK.
[image]

Inside of this folder should be another folder called "platform-tools".
[image]

### Update your PATH

You'll want to add this folder to your PATH and remove the old one.

[image]

### Restart Android Studio

For the changes to take effect, you'll need to restart the IDE.

File -> Invalidate Caches -> Invalidate and Restart

### Another Solution

If the above doesn't work, you can also uninstall and reinstall platform-tools using the sdkmanager command.

```
sdkmanager --uninstall "platform-tools"
```

Once platform-tools is uninstalled, you can use the SDK Manager in Android Studio to reinstall.

Comment: Reinstalling platform-tools worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: I did everything as you said. But still, it does not resolve the issue.

Comment: I just restarted my system to fix this issue

Comment: Restarting appears to be necessary *on Linux* too to clear net interfaces.

Comment: I tried most other answers, but what really worked for me is your answer. Just unhceck platform-tools in Android Studio, hit apply, check platform-tools, hit apply, and it works.

Answer (score 6):

**File** > **Invalidate Caches...** worked for me:

[image: Android Studio File menu]

Select **Invalidate and Restart**:
[image: Invalidate Caches window]

Answer (score 5):

To solve this, you can view this solution on Youtube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BmetRGkmH6g
or

- go to your Android studio
- settings
- head to debugger untick ADB mDNS and apply
- then head back and tick the ADB and try running again, that should work.

Comment: This worked for me in Android Studio 2023.2.1 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

If your PC has a wifi adapter, disable it.  Fixed it for me.

I just updated windows 10 to 20H2 and whatever recent service pack it's been asking for, for months.  I think it re-enabled my wifi adapter, or did something to break adb mdns.

Anyways, none of these suggestions worked.  Hopefully this saves someone 2 hours.

Answer (score 3):

I have same issue , but i downloaded "ADB Wi-Fi" plugin and it works perfectly for Wi-Fi pairing.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to restart your PC after you have updated everything. this may restart ADB server totally.

Answer (score 2):

if your PC have **wireless ADAPTER** like TP-LINK and there is no cable to the router. this will broken the connection. I solved this issue with:

1. Create A hospot in your phone
2. connect your pc to the phone hotspot instead.
3. then use pairing with code (on your phone)
4. input in android studio terminal : `adb pair <ipaddress-pair>:<port-pair>`
5. input password
6. `adb connect <ipaddress-connect>:<port-connect>`

maybe this will save your 2 hours

Comment: omg, no. just toggle mDNS option in Android Studio Settings

Answer (score 0):

I tried all suggested steps, which were well explained but unfortunately didn't solve the problem for me. I found out that by **disabling** the network adapter for my NordVPN, the issue suddenly disappeared. If you are using Windows, I'd suggest you check if you have any network adapter which could be disabled.

You can enter this path (`Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections`) in your top bar of the Control Panel if you would not like to click through some steps, otherwise just follow these steps:

1. Go to "Control Panel" in Windows
2. Click on "Network and Internet"
3. Click on "Network and Sharing Center"
4. Click on "Change adapter settings"
5. Right-mouse click on any adapter you wish to disable

After these changes, check your Android Studio to see if disabling the adapter solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall and ALLOW to incoming and outgoing traffic.

Hope it's helpful! :)

Answer (score 0):

the problem with above solution for me is i have to keep unchecking and rechecking everytime

there is a simple permanent fix:

add the android sdk path to windows security exeption: C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9TRD.png)

Answer (score -1):

Just try using terminal with as normal as before just change adb to .\adb and connect your device with wireless debugging...